# Understanding %%i and %%k in a Windows batch file

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to understand a Windows batch file with the following statements:

```
:GetVSCommonToolsDirHelper32
@for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "%1\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" /v "10.0"') DO (
@if "%%i"=="10.0" (
    @SET "VS100COMNTOOLS=%%k"
)
)
```

I understand the %1 parameters, but what does `%%i` and `%%k` specify?

FYI, the statement is called using a label with this statement:

```
call :GetVSCommonToolsDirHelper32 HKCU > nul 2>&1
```

Any additional information about this code would be very useful too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its just the way you format modifiable variables in the FOR see http://www.computerhope.com/forhlp.htm
From that page, it seems the %%k is taken from the tokens part.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I read the article, then ran the "reg query" statement from my dos prompt. That returns a line with 3 tokens separated by spaces which gets parsed and each token put into the variable declared by %i, then %j and %k respectively. So %%k refers to the value of the 3rd token, which is what is returned.